# SpriteKit touches

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

please help me with abstract touches began method.
I have this method at scene, VZChurch it's SKSpriteNode. Is there way to transfer touches began method inside Subclass of SKSpriteNode, because i think that 5-6 if else statement not shine decision, so i try to found way to migrate touches began method in every subclass of SKSpriteNode

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self.mapStaticGeometry];
    SKNode *node = [self.mapStaticGeometry nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"church"]) {

        VZChurch *obj = (VZChurch *)node;
        obj.requestedAnimation = VZAnimationStateTouch;
        [obj runAnimation];
    } else if ...n iterations
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to avoid what you're asking is to subclass an `SKNode` (or `SKSpriteNode`) for each node. This then allows you handle the `touchesBegan` inside the subclassed node.

So just subclass a SKNode (or SKSpriteNode since VZChurch is a sprite) and handling the `touchesBegan` in `VZChurch`'s it it's own methods file. Then if you have other SKSprites, do the same thing, subclass each sprite and handle the `touchesBegan` inside their respective subclassed methods file.

Comment: Thanks, i already did it, and it doesn't work, but i found,that problem was in uiscrollview with zPosition higher, then zPosition of static view)